# What is "key-press-modifiers"

Tags: pantheon

In dconf-editor > org > onboard > keyboard, there is teh key-press-modifiers option, set by default to `{'button3':'SHIFT'}`. I believe this sometimes interferes with some vim commands. What is `button3` and what is this needed for? If I would like to disable it, what would I set it to?

Answer (score 1):

It is a setting of `onboard` (the on-screen keyboard).

You can use the uppercase letters (and symbols on the other keys) either with shift-click or with the `button3` click (right-click in my case).

If you don't use `onboard` you don't need to disable it either.